# iOS Objective C progress bar update in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, timer, progress

I've run various types of code to try and make a progress bar increment for x seconds and continue to do so even when in the background. Currently the bar just resumes from where it left off, via the timer, when going from background to focus.

How can I continue the timer even when the user minimizes the app?

Answer (score -1):

Declare a NSTimer property in .h. Then call it from anywhere like :

```
self.nstimer=  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.10 self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And inside the method (audiocontroller is another class property):

```
- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer
{

 //  Progress bar value
    progressView.progress = ((float)recievedData / (float) xpectedTotalSize);

 }
```

It will continue call the method even the app is in background. You can cancel this method calling from applicationDidBecomeActive() method.

Comment: Many thanks for this! Would this be able to progress a process bar? Such as: _bar.progress += 0.1/120;

Comment: You can implement any UI update from this method. I did it for my projects also. Just apply and see. Please accept and upvote my answer if get help.  @user6934446